# Currency conversions on sales figures

Tags: powerbi, dax, currency

I have a table called **1- Invoices report** which looks like this:

| Currency IND | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| EBF | 66.3 |
| BFE | 65.2 |
| CAF | 54.3 |
| BGE | 65.2 |
| CAE | 87.5 |
| AED | 45.6 |

I have to calculate **Net Revenue**. The Net Revenue has to be in USD currency. The conversion rate goes as follows:

| Currency IND | USD Conversion (Divide by this value) |
| --- | --- |
| EBF | 0.505 |
| BFE | 2.8832 |
| CAF | 2.66 |
| BGE | 0.5851 |
| CAE | 0.4775 |
| AED | 1.5 |

I have tried using this code for making a Net Revenue Column but it is not giving the right answers:

```
Net Revenue = 
IF(
    '1- Invoices report'[Currency IND]="EBF",('1- Invoices report'[Revenue]/0.505),
    IF('1- Invoices report'[Currency IND]="BFE",('1- Invoices report'[Revenue]/2.8832),
    IF('1- Invoices report'[Currency IND]="CAF",('1- Invoices report'[Revenue]/2.66),
    IF('1- Invoices report'[Currency IND]="BGE",('1- Invoices report'[Revenue]/0.5851),
    IF('1- Invoices report'[Currency IND]="CAE",('1- Invoices report'[Revenue]/0.4775),
    ('1- Invoices report'[Revenue]/1.5)
)))))
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Put your conversion rate into a separate table and Power BI will create a one-to-one relationship on 'Currency IND'. (Note that in general this would be a one-to-many relationship when you have multiple revenues per currency.)

[image]

Now you can put 'Currency IND', 'Revenue' and 'USD Conversion' into one table and Power BI will create an implicit measure (sum aggregation) for the revenue.

You can now add your 'Net Revenue' (in USD) with the following measure:

```
Net Revenue = 
SUMX(
    '1- Invoices report',
    DIVIDE(
        '1- Invoices report'[Revenue], 
        RELATED('Conversion rate'[USD Conversion])
    )
)
```

and the result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: That relationship would normally be one Conversion Rate to Many Invoice reports.

Comment: Yep, the provided sample data is a bit too special.

Comment: Makes sense - adjusted.